# Using Get-EventLog in PowerShell how can I show only 10 characters in the message

Tags: powershell, get-eventlog

I currently have the code below:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application 
| Where-Object EventID -EQ 1033 
| Select-Object EventID, Message
```

So my question is how can I just show the first 10 characters of the Message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the substring method on your message property.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | Select-Object EventID, @{Label='Message';Expression={$_.Message.Substring(0,10)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as a follow up:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application 
| Where-Object EventID -EQ 1033 
| Select-Object EventID, @{l="Message";e={$_.message.substring(0,10)}}
```

Comment: That would only get the first 9 characters :) the first parameter of substring is what index to start at, while the second is how many characters you want.